# Add a video player to a UITableView Cell *Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to have different local video files play on a TableCell. My issue is where can I place the PlayVideo function (the TableViewController class or the TableViewCell class) and figuring out how to set the frame inside the cell. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having your `PlayVideo` function in your TableViewCell subclass as part of a protocol's method, and set your TableViewController as the TableViewCell's delegate for that protocol.

That way your TableViewController has access to the video URL in the data source, and to the cell's `PlayVideo` method, which you'd call in the TableViewController as something like `tableViewCell.playVideo()`

You can probably set the video's frame in the TableViewCell class, and the cell's frame in the tableView datasource's `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

Cheers!